# How to make a column in lighting datable call JavaScript function?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-datatable, onclick

How to make a column in lighting datable call JavaScript function? This column has to be editable at the same time. Something like in the picture below - but when clicked the account name has to call a JS function. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: That'd be confusing from UX perspective, why not use action buttons?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This is a client requirement, the field needs to be clickable(in our case a filename or folder name - if it is a file, then it should download the file else navigate to the child folder), at the same time editable so they can rename the file. I showed the action button approach, they were not really okay with.